# PyQtGraph, make two plots match eachothers visual range (produces offset)?

Tags: python, range, offset, pyqtgraph

I am trying to make two plots have the same visual range for X and need both to change when one or the other is changed.

Here is some bare minimum Python code showing what I am trying to do:
(Only the top plot is connected to the bottom plot, try moving,zooming and scaling it)

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class NoiseGenerator():
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal

    def read(self):
        y = np.random.rand(512)
        self.signal.emit(y)

    def close(self):
        pass


class AnimationWidget(pg.LayoutWidget):

    read_collected = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimationWidget, self).__init__()

        self.noisePlot_Top = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.noisePlot_Top.setLabel('bottom', 'Noise', units='Jigawatts')
        self.noiseCurve_Top = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.noisePlot_Top.addItem(self.noiseCurve_Top)

        self.noisePlot_Bot = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.noisePlot_Bot.setLabel('bottom', 'Noise', units='Jigawatts')
        self.noiseCurve_Bot = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.noisePlot_Bot.addItem(self.noiseCurve_Bot)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.noisePlot_Top)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.noisePlot_Bot)   

        self.noisePlot_Top.sigXRangeChanged.connect(self.updateRegion) 

    def updateRegion(self):
        left,right = self.noiseCurve_Top.getViewBox().viewRange()[0]
        self.noiseCurve_Bot.getViewBox().setRange(xRange=(left,right))

    def update(self, chunk):
        #print "---------"
        #print self.averagefft.getViewBox().viewRange()[0]
        #print self.averagefft2.getViewBox().viewRange()[0]
        #print np.array(self.averagefft.getViewBox().viewRange()[0]) - np.array(self.averagefft2.getViewBox().viewRange()[0])

        self.noiseCurve_Top.setData(chunk)
        self.noiseCurve_Bot.setData(chunk)


class MainApp():

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    win.setCentralWidget(widget)
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
    win.show()    
    win.resize(1000,600)

    def __init__(self):

        w = AnimationWidget()
        w.read_collected.connect(w.update)
        self.layout.addWidget(w)

        noise = NoiseGenerator(w.read_collected)

        self.t = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.t.timeout.connect(noise.read)
        self.t.start(100) #QTimer takes ms

        self.app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = MainApp()
```

Whenever the range of the top plot changes I update the range of the bottom plot using these lines:

```
def updateRegion(self):
    left,right = self.noiseCurve_Top.getViewBox().viewRange()[0]
    self.noiseCurve_Bot.getViewBox().setRange(xRange=(left,right))
```

However once the top plot has been changed the bottom plot will no longer exactly match the visual range of the top, and there appears to be some offset.

[image: Range Not Equal]

Is there a way I can have bottom's range match the top's range hopefully without any offset?

Thanks.

[update]

I was curious if the issue had something to do with timing (after the XRangeChanged event fires) so I moved the lines of code to try updating the viewBox range for every time the plot was updated and still got the same offset. So I am convinced its something to do with the way I am retrieving and setting the range values.

**[Solution]**

As suggested by three_pineapples I was not aware of the existence of the setLink methods, which make doing this task incredibly simple.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class NoiseGenerator():
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal

    def read(self):
        y = np.random.rand(512)
        self.signal.emit(y)

    def close(self):
        pass


class AnimationWidget(pg.LayoutWidget):

    read_collected = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimationWidget, self).__init__()

        self.noisePlot_Top = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.noisePlot_Top.setLabel('bottom', 'Noise', units='Jigawatts')
        self.noiseCurve_Top = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.noisePlot_Top.addItem(self.noiseCurve_Top)

        self.noisePlot_Bot = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.noisePlot_Bot.setLabel('bottom', 'Noise', units='Jigawatts')
        self.noiseCurve_Bot = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.noisePlot_Bot.addItem(self.noiseCurve_Bot)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.noisePlot_Top)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.noisePlot_Bot)

        self.noisePlot_Top.getViewBox().setXLink(self.noisePlot_Bot) #Link the two plot's X ranges

    def update(self, chunk):

        self.noiseCurve_Top.setData(chunk)
        self.noiseCurve_Bot.setData(chunk)


class MainApp():

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    win.setCentralWidget(widget)
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
    win.show()
    win.resize(1000,600)

    def __init__(self):

        w = AnimationWidget()
        w.read_collected.connect(w.update)
        self.layout.addWidget(w)

        noise = NoiseGenerator(w.read_collected)

        self.t = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.t.timeout.connect(noise.read)
        self.t.start(100) #QTimer takes ms

        self.app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = MainApp()
```

[image: Range Now Equal]

Caution:
Depending in which order you link the two plots it may have some significance if you programmatically change a plot's data or its range - I was able to resolve a small issue by simply flipping the items:

```
# Can be
self.noisePlot_Top.getViewBox().setXLink(self.noisePlot_Bot)
# - or -
self.noisePlot_Bot.getViewBox().setXLink(self.noisePlot_Top)
# But not both
```

Comment: Pyqtgraph has this functionality built in. You want to find the `setXLink` and `setYLink` methods. I can't remember which objects these are method of, but hopefully that's enough to point you in the right direction!

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!